# Parse GEO XML to list all suburbs

Tags: asp.net, xml

I'm attempting to grab a list of all of the suburbs in Australia using the below code which pulls back an xml document.  I've managed to grab a list of the states but then need to grab each suburb for those states which is more complicated then I'm used to.

```
Dim requests As System.Net.HttpWebRequest

requests = WebRequest.Create("http://www.parkrun.com.au/wp-content/themes/parkrun/xml/geo.xml")

requests.ContentType = "text/xml"
requests.Method = "post"
requests.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; InfoPath.1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)"

requests.CookieContainer = New CookieContainer

Dim response As System.Net.HttpWebResponse = requests.GetResponse

Dim XMLResponse As New XmlDocument
XMLResponse.Load(response.GetResponseStream)

Dim Country As XmlNodeList = XMLResponse.SelectNodes("geo/r/r")
```

The output of country is below:

```
<r id="19" n="Australian Capital Territory" la="-35.234051" lo="149.073486" z="9" pid="3" u="" />
<r id="5" n="New South Wales" la="-32.713355" lo="147.832031" z="6" pid="3" u="" />
<r id="31" n="Northern Territory" la="-14.349547" lo="133.154296" z="6" pid="3" u="" />
<r id="4" n="Queensland" la="-25.264568" lo="148.293457" z="6" pid="3" u="" />
<r id="33" n="Singapore" la="1.361790" lo="103.820114" z="11" pid="3" u="" />
<r id="30" n="South Australia" la="-33.378858" lo="135.703125" z="6" pid="3" u="" />
<r id="28" n="Tasmania" la="-42.081916" lo="146.788330" z="7" pid="3" u="" />
<r id="6" n="Victoria" la="-36.226550" lo="144.909667" z="6" pid="3" u="" />
<r id="27" n="Western Australia" la="-29.699259" lo="119.104532" z="6" pid="3" u="" />
```

So I'd like to loop through each state, eg Australian Capital Territory, New South Wales, etc, for each one of those they have an id value, that id value matches the r value in each suburb, for example Minnippi below is in Queensland (Queensland id = 4 and Minnippi r = 4)

```
<e n="minnippi" m="Minnippi" c="3" id="670" r="4" la="-27.493310" lo="153.118679"/>
```

The full xml is at http://www.parkrun.com.au/wp-content/themes/parkrun/xml/geo.xml.

Basically I'm wanting to build an object of states and suburbs within each state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this XPath to get `<e>` elements with specific `r` attribute value :

```
geo/e[@r='put the country id here']
```

Example in VB :

```
Dim Country As XmlNodeList = XMLResponse.SelectNodes("geo/r/r")
For Each xmlNode As XmlNode In Country
    Dim id As String = xmlNode.Attributes("id").Value
    Dim suburbs As XmlNodeList = xmlNode.SelectNodes("geo/e[@r='" & id & "']")
    'here you can construct object of current state and it's suburbs'
Next
```